# How to prevent images from appearing on the screen in Matplolib? Python

Tags: python, linux, image, matplotlib, plot

I have a quick question I am trying to solve. I have a script that processes about 2000 files, generates images and saves images to either PDF or image format. But I am not able to prevent images from appearing on the screen. I read and researched but couldn't solve my problem. I assume there is something wrong with my backend set up in Matplotlib. But I am not an expert in that. I tried using matplotlib.use('Agg') as stated on the website but it didnt help. 
So, if you could help me figure out whats going on wrong I d appreciate that.
Thanks a lot!

System: Ubuntu 13.04
Matplotlib: 1.2.1
Python 2.7.4

Here is how importing part of my script looks:

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator, AutoMinorLocator, ScalarFormatter
from pylab import *
```

EDIT: posting more code. It's just a part of it. I have a function:

```
def plot_vi(t, s1, s2, s3, charttitle, chartnote, celllocation, filename):

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 12))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
l1, = ax1.plot(t, s1, 'r-', linewidth=0.7)
l2, = ax1.plot(t, s3, '-', linewidth=0.7, color='#00ff00')
ax1.set_xlabel('Test Time (hours)')
# Make the y-axis label and tick labels match the line color.
ax1.set_ylabel('Voltage (Volts)', color='r')
for tl in ax1.get_yticklabels():
    tl.set_color('r')

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
l3, = ax2.plot(t, s2, 'b-', linewidth=0.7)
ax2.set_ylabel('Current (Amps)', color='b')
for tl in ax2.get_yticklabels():
    tl.set_color('b')

minorLocator   = AutoMinorLocator()
ax2.xaxis.set_minor_locator(minorLocator)
majorLocator   = MultipleLocator(1)
minorLocator   = MultipleLocator(0.2)
ax2.yaxis.set_major_locator(majorLocator)
ax2.yaxis.set_minor_locator(minorLocator)
majorLocator   = MultipleLocator(0.1)
minorLocator   = MultipleLocator(0.02)
ax1.yaxis.set_major_locator(majorLocator)
ax1.yaxis.set_minor_locator(minorLocator)
ax1.xaxis.grid(color='gray')
ax1.yaxis.grid(color='gray')
lgd = legend([l1, l3, l2], ['voltage', 'current', 'auxiliary'], bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2)

title(charttitle, fontsize=16)
figtext(0.01, 0.027, chartnote, color='#707070')
figtext(0.01, 0.01, celllocation, color='#707070')
fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.85) 
plt.savefig(filename, dpi=100)plot_vi(t, s1, s2, s3, ChartTitle, ChartNote, CellLocation, PLOTFILENAME)
    plt.savefig(pp, format='pdf')
```

Then I ran that function:

```
 plot_vi(t, s1, s2, s3, ChartTitle, ChartNote, CellLocation, PLOTFILENAME)
 plt.savefig(pp, format='pdf')
```

Comment: The images appear on the screen momentarily and disappear quickly, or they appear and stay?

Comment: They stay forever. I have to manually close them.

Comment: Check out my answer below; it may help.

Comment: Could you reformat your code?  It looks like the last two lines may haven gotten mangled :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, looks like I found some kind of a solution. I forced the matplotlib to switch the backend:

```
matplotlib.pyplot.switch_backend('Agg')
```

After that I am not getting thousands of GUI windows on my screen. Have not tested with PDFs yet though.

Source: [from here](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=switch_backend#matplotlib.pyplot.switch_backend)

Answer (score 1):

You **may** have a place in your script where you say `plt.show()`.  Replace that with `plt.savefig('fig-name.pdf')`, where `fig-name.pdf` is the name you want to save as.  If you want to save as a .png, you just change the extension to `.png`, etc.

Here is some [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/faq/howto_faq.html#save-multiple-plots-to-one-pdf-file) about saving multiple images to a pdf; it may help you out as well.

Comment: Nooo, its not that easy. I would ve mentioned plt.show() part. I am not using it. I can post more code if needed.

Comment: I suppose it was wishful thinking on my part.  Posting more code would be helpful.

Comment: Spotted that error at the beginning:
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/__init__.py:1035: UserWarning:  This call to matplotlib.use() has no effect
because the the backend has already been chosen;
matplotlib.use() must be called *before* pylab, matplotlib.pyplot,
or matplotlib.backends is imported for the first time.

  warnings.warn(_use_error_msg)

Comment: I think you're still in interactive mode (ipython -pylab?), use `plt.ioff()` on top of your script to turn interactive mode off.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure :-

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
```

Place before import backend_pdf :-

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator, AutoMinorLocator, ScalarFormatter
from pylab import *
```

Comment: Nope, tried that already. There is something wrong in my backend I guess, as I d mentioned. Not sure what though.